# Unable to find custom indexer class 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index'

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-lucene-index

I am using apache-cassandra-3.0.10. I have placed cassandra lucene jar with version 3.0.10.3 in cassandra lib folder. When i am trying to create lucene index it is showing the message Unable to find custom indexer class 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index'. As per the lucene documentation 3.0.10 jar is compatible with cassandra version 3.0.10. Then why this error is occuring. Can any one help me out of this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cassandra lucene jar  3.0.10 was downloaded from maven repository and it was broken. I generated own jar file from their github repository and it was working fine

Answer (score 0):

**Put the stratio lucene jar into all of your cassandra node's lib folder and 
Restart all the node.**

Comment: Hi,I have already added lucene jar to the lib folder of cassandra. But it is not working

Comment: Did you restart all the node ??